# How do I get Parsec to let me call `read` :: Int?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I've got the following, which type-checks:

```
p_int = liftA read (many (char ' ') *> many1 digit <* many (char ' '))
```

Now, as the function name implies, I want it to give me an Int. But if I do this:

```
p_int = liftA read (many (char ' ') *> many1 digit <* many (char ' ')) :: Int
```

I get this type error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `f0 b0'
In the return type of a call of `liftA'
In the expression:
    liftA read (many (char ' ') *> many1 digit <* many (char ' ')) ::
      Int
In an equation for `p_int':
    p_int
      = liftA read (many (char ' ') *> many1 digit <* many (char ' ')) ::
          Int
```

Is there a simpler, cleaner way to parse integers that may have whitespace? Or a way to fix this?

Ultimately, I want this to be part of the following:

```
betaLine = string "BETA " *> p_int <*> p_int  <*> p_int <*>
           p_int <*> p_parallel <*> p_exposure <* eol
```

which is to parse lines that look like this:

```
BETA  6 11 5 24 -1 oiiio
```

So I can eventually call a BetaPair constructor which will need those values (some as Int, some as other types like [Exposure] and Parallel)

(if you're curious, this is a parser for a file format that represents, among other things, hydrogen-bonded beta-strand pairs in proteins. I have no control over the file format!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p_int` is a parser that produces an `Int`, so the type would be `Parser Int` or similar¹.

```
p_int = liftA read (many (char ' ') *> many1 digit <* many (char ' ')) :: Parser Int
```

Alternatively, you can type the `read` function, `(read :: String -> Int)` to tell the compiler which type the expression has.

```
p_int = liftA (read :: String -> Int) (many (char ' ') *> many1 digit <* many (char ' ')) :: Int
```

As for the cleaner ways, consider replacing `many (char ' ')` with `spaces`.

¹ `ParsecT x y z Int`, for example.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! typing the read function is just what I needed; I was just getting the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 8):

> How do I get Parsec to let me call `read :: Int`?

A second answer is "Don't use read".

Using `read` is equivalent to re-parsing data you have already parsed - so using it within a Parsec parser is a code smell. Parsing natural numbers is harmless enough, but `read` has different failure semantics to Parsec and it is tailored to Haskell's lexical syntax so using it for more complicated number formats is problematic.

If you don't want to go to the trouble of defining a `LanguageDef` and using Parsec's `Token` module here is a natural number parser that doesn't use read:

```
-- | Needs @foldl'@ from Data.List and 
-- @digitToInt@ from Data.Char.
--
positiveNatural :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Int
positiveNatural = 
    foldl' (\a i -> a * 10 + digitToInt i) 0 <$> many1 digit
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Indeed, what I'm parsing is merely a data file format, so a full LanguageDef doesn't seem worthwhile. Indeed, I also have to parse negativeLogProbability values, which (as logs of probabilities) are either '*' (zero probability) or a Double (nonzero probability). How would you propose parsing Double without using read?

Comment: Hi @Noah - for parsing doubles I would delegate to the master and see Daan Leijen did it in the source code of the Parsec.Token module.

Answer (score 1):

You may find

```
Text-Megaparsec-Lexer.integer :: MonadParsec s m Char => m Integer
```

does what you want.

The vanilla parsec library seems to be missing a number of obvious parsers, which has led to the rise of "batteries included" parsec derivative packages.  I suppose the parsec maintainers will get around to betteries eventually.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-4.2.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Lexer.html

UPDATE

or with vanilla parsec:

```
Prelude Text.Parsec Text.Parsec.Language Text.Parsec.Token> parse ( integer . makeTokenParser $ haskellStyle ) "integer" "-1234"
Right (-1234)
```