# How to parse an Integer with parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I was expecting to find a function

```
integer :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Integer
```

or maybe even

```
natural :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Integer
```

in the standard libraries, but I did not find one.

What is the standard way of parsing plain natural numbers directly to an `Integer`?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html#v:integer

Comment: Thanks. But that does more than I want. It parses white space around, and I need to make a token parser first....

Comment: Can't you convert the `Read` instance for `Integer` into a `Parser` by using the `reads` function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is what I often do is to use the expression

```
read <$> many1 digit
```

which can have type `Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Integer` (or simply `Parser Integer`).

I don’t like the use of the the partial function `read`, but when the parser succeeds I know that the `read` will succeed, and it is somewhat readable.

Comment: Could you include a type signature for clarity?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source of [`Text.Parsec.Token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html), it seems Parsec doesn't have a dedicated function for it. They do give a default definition for the `decimal` field of `GenLanguageDef`. `decimal` is defined similar to:

```
decimal = do
    digits <- many1 baseDigit
    let n = foldl (\x d -> base*x + toInteger (digitToInt d)) 0 digits
    seq n (return n)
  where
    base = 10
    baseDigit = digit
```

Here, `digit` is taken from `Text.Parsec.Char` and `digitToInt` from `Data.Char`.

There's also a default definition for `natural`, which, by default, also parses octal and hexadecimal numbers, and skips trailing whitespace.

Comment: Also, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10726784/824425) is really similar, quite a bit shorter thanks to its applicative style, and uses `foldl'` instead of `foldl` plus a `seq` at the wrong place :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a package [**`parsec3-numbers`** <sup>[hackage]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec3-numbers) that provides functions to parse numbers in some formats.

Probably the most interesting ones are [**`int :: (Integral i, Stream s m Char) => ParsecT s u m i`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec3-numbers-0.1.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Number.html#g:5) and [**`nat :: (Integral i, Stream s m Char) => ParsecT s u m i`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec3-numbers-0.1.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Number.html#g:5) which parse integral numbers and natural numbers respectively. These do not only parse the numbers as decimal format, but also as octal and hexadecimal. The package also contains some parsers that restrict parsing with a specific radix, so only decimal numbers for example.