# "Batteries" for Parsec in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am new to Haskell, and I have been trying to write a JSON parser using Parsec as an exercise. This has mostly been going well, I am able to parse lists and objects with relatively little code which is also readable (great!). However, for JSON I also need to parse primitives like

- Integers (possibly signed)
- Floats (possibly using scientific notation such as "3.4e-8")
- Strings with e.g. escaped quotes

I was hoping to find ready to use parsers for things like these as part of Parsec. The closest I get is the Parsec.Tokens module (defines `integer` and friends), but those parsers require a "language definition" that seems way beyond what I should have to make to parse something as simple as JSON -- it appears to be designed for programming languages.

So my questions are:

1. Are the functions in Parsec.Token the right way to go here? If so, how to make a suitable language definition?
2. Are "primitive" parsers for integers etc defined somewhere else? Maybe in another package?
3. Am I supposed to write these kinds of low-level parsers myself? I can see myself reusing them frequently... (obscure scientific data formats etc.)

I have noticed that a question on this site says Megaparsec has these primitives included [1], but I suppose these cannot be used with parsec.

Related questions:

[How do I get Parsec to let me call `read` :: Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726085/how-do-i-get-parsec-to-let-me-call-read-int/10726784#10726784)

[How to parse an Integer with parsec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171005/how-to-parse-an-integer-with-parsec)

Comment: You can just pass in empty strings and lists and always-failing parsers for the options that do not apply to you (which I guess is all of them).

Comment: If you can, please use `megaparsec`. It is a better modern rewrite of `parsec` (and is actually b king maintained).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are the functions in Parsec.Token the right way to go here?

Yes, they are. If you don't care about the [minutiae specified by a language definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html#t:GenLanguageDef) (i.e. you don't plan to use the parsers which depend on them, such as [`identifier` or `reserved`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html#t:GenTokenParser)), just use [`emptyDef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Language.html#v:emptyDef) as a default:

```
import Text.Parsec
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P
import Text.Parsec.Language (emptyDef)

lexer = P.makeTokenParser emptyDef

integer = P.integer lexer
```

As you noted, this feels unnecesarily clunky for your use case. It is worth mentioning that *megaparsec* (cf. [Alec's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42598845/batteries-for-parsec-in-haskell#comment72328887_42598845)) provides a corresponding [`integer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-5.2.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Lexer.html#v:integer) parser without the ceremony. (The flip side is that *megaparsec* doesn't try to bake in support for e.g. reserved words, but that [isn't difficult to implement](https://mrkkrp.github.io/megaparsec/tutorials/parsing-simple-imperative-language.html#lexer) in the cases you actually need it.)