# Haskell Parsec - Optimize int parsing

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am using `import Text.Parsec.Text` and `import Text.Parsec.Char` to parse some data that includes integers. I am using the following code to parse integers.

```
p_int :: Parser Int
p_int = read <$> ((++) <$> option "" (string "-") <*> many1 digit)
```

I profiled my program and turns out that the above snippet takes >90% of the execution time. How do I optimize the above code?

I came across `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Number` module that contains an `int` function to parse integers. However, its type is `int :: Integral i => CharParser st i` which is not compatible with the `Text` based parser I am using as evident by the error below.

```
   • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Text’
      Expected type: Parser Int
        Actual type: Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char.CharParser () Int
```

**UPDATE**
I replaced `Text.Parsec.Text` with `Text.Parsec.String` and replaced my int parsing function with `int` from `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Number`. This improved execution time by ~40%. But still the performance is worse that Python. Profiling shows that ~80% time is being consumed in int parsing. Does this mean Parsec is just slow?

```
COST CENTRE    MODULE                               SRC                                                       %time %alloc

sign           Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Number Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Number.hs:277:1-73           34.4   39.8
number         Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Number Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Number.hs:(321,1)-(323,18)   26.7   27.5
numberValue    Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Number Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Number.hs:(327,1)-(328,74)   10.2    6.7
zeroNumber     Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Number Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Number.hs:(300,1)-(301,56)    6.0   10.0
...

....

int                Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Number Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Number.hs:273:1-17         499          0    1.4    1.6    79.5   86.5
```

Comment: You should import `import Text.Parsec.String` instead of `Text.Parsec.Text` here.

Comment: Using `read` isn't going to help you with efficiency. I would check https://stackoverflow.com/a/10726784/1248563

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have updated the question with my experience with `Text.Parsec.String`. Do you have any more advise please?

Comment: I think Parsec is just slow. I replaced it with Attoparsec and am seeing another 60% (80% over my custom int function from original question) speed-up without any optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced Parsec with Attoparsec and without any optimization it is now 80% faster. Also the "total alloc" is down from over 3GB to 507MB.

The API is very similar between the two libraries so it was not at all difficult to migrate. I will try to optimize it further if possible and see how fast it can get.